# Segmentation fault due to unknown error in code

Tags: arrays, c, memory

I am doin the fisrt day in AoC, it requires you to add up to amount of calories consumed by each elf and you are give a txt file with the required details. My code is able to get through 4 rotations of finding elfs calories but stops at the fifth due to a segmentaion fault, i assume it is somthing to do with the line variable but cannot figure it out. Any help will be appriciated.

I have tried to free the memory of the variable line after it has been used and then re allocate it again but that seems to makle no differents. It seems to work fine for 4 atempts but i get this out put
"""

Elf number 0 calorie intake was 47524

Elf number 1 calorie intake was 18774

Elf number 2 calorie intake was 11597

Elf number 3 calorie intake was 10625

[1]    97205 segmentation fault  ./a.out

"""

I expected the memory to be cleared but it seems that is not the case.
could someone please help or explain why the segmentaion fault is occuring.

my code is the following:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFF 500

int array[BUFF];

void read_file(FILE *file, char *line, const size_t lineSize, int counter) {
        int calorie = 0;
        while (strlen(fgets(line, lineSize, file)) != 1) {
                calorie += atoi(line);
        }
        printf("Elf number %d calorie intake was %d\n\n", counter, calorie);
}



int main() {
        int counter = 0;
        int calorie = 0;
        const size_t line_size = 6;
        FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r"); 
        while (counter <= 500) {
                char * line = malloc(line_size);
                read_file(fp, line, line_size, counter);
                counter++;
                free(line);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

`

The contents of the first 50 or so lines are:

```
4514
8009
6703
1811
4881
3905
3933
9436
4332

3059
15715
11597
10625
8486

4556
10613
4087
11287
12020
1412

5320
9757
10646
7373
1197
3486
4359

16319
22687
5272

6167
2478
4950
5513
6113
2739
6805
4488
6555
2752

2198
2528
3432
2218
3283
1400
1932
3438
1834
1050
4766
5218
3033
3410
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file you're reading? You should probably restructure your loop a bit to be sire you don't pass `NULL` to `strlen` or `atoi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. When we hit end of file, `fgets` returns `NULL` which is passed to `strlen` causing a segfault
2. The `strlen` call was used to detect a blank line. A simpler way is to just check the first char in the line.
3. Loop in `main` doesn't stop upon EOF
4. `read_file` does *not* return an EOF flag.
5. `main` does `malloc/free` on *each* loop iteration. A `malloc` before and a `free` after the loop is better
6. No `fclose` in `main`

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFF 500

int array[BUFF];

#if 0
void
#else
// RETURNS: 0=eof
int
#endif
read_file(FILE * file, char *line, const size_t lineSize, int counter)
{
    int calorie = 0;

// NOTE/BUG: this segfaults in strlen because fgets returns NULL (i.e. this
// means EOF on file)
#if 0
    while (strlen(fgets(line, lineSize, file)) != 1) {
        calorie += atoi(line);
    }
    printf("Elf number %d calorie intake was %d\n\n", counter, calorie);
#else
    // loop until EOF
    int eof = 0;
    while (1) {
        eof = (fgets(line, lineSize, file) == NULL);
        if (eof)
            break;

        // stop on blank line
        if (line[0] == 0)
            break;
        if (line[0] == '\n')
            break;

        calorie += atoi(line);
    }

    printf("Elf number %d calorie intake was %d\n\n", counter, calorie);

    return eof;
#endif
}

int
main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int calorie = 0;
    const size_t line_size = 6;

    FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");

// NOTE/BUG: doesn't stop on EOF
// NOTE/BUG: no need to malloc/free on every loop
#if 0
    while (counter <= 500) {
        char *line = malloc(line_size);

        read_file(fp, line, line_size, counter);
        counter++;

        free(line);
    }
#else
    char *line = malloc(line_size);
    while (counter <= 500) {
        if (read_file(fp, line, line_size, counter))
            break;
        counter++;
    }
    free(line);
#endif

#if 1
    fclose(fp);
#endif

    return 1;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the cleaned up code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFF 500

int array[BUFF];

// RETURNS: 0=eof
int
read_file(FILE * file, char *line, const size_t lineSize, int counter)
{
    int calorie = 0;

    // loop until EOF
    int eof = 0;
    while (1) {
        eof = (fgets(line, lineSize, file) == NULL);
        if (eof)
            break;

        // stop on blank line
        if (line[0] == 0)
            break;
        if (line[0] == '\n')
            break;

        calorie += atoi(line);
    }

    printf("Elf number %d calorie intake was %d\n\n", counter, calorie);

    return eof;
}

int
main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int calorie = 0;
    const size_t line_size = 6;

    FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");

    char *line = malloc(line_size);
    while (counter <= 500) {
        if (read_file(fp, line, line_size, counter))
            break;
        counter++;
    }
    free(line);

    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```